# Error with DynamoDB Query

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database, nosql

I am attempting to query a string set item from DynamoDB

#### Error :

```
{
    "errorMessage":"{
        "message": "Unexpected key 'Key' found in params",
        "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
        "time": "2016-01-06T08:24:02.183Z"
    }"
}
```

#### Code :

```
var table = 'users'
var params = {
    TableName : table,
    Key : {
        'userType': { 'S': event.type },
        'username': { 'S': event.username }
    }
}

ddb.query (params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // Oh well
    } else {
        context.succeed (data.Item)
    }
})
```

I want my system to allow multiple users to have the same username - sounds silly, its for a good reason.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Get Item

- **Requires** : TableName, Key (at least hash)
- **Optional** : AttributesToGet, ConsistentRead, ExpressionAttributeNames, etc.

If you change `ddb.query` to `ddb.getItem` - that code should work perfectly.

So your getItem product would look like:

```
var table = 'users'
var params = {
    TableName : table,
    Key : {
        'userType': { S: event.type },
        'username': { S: event.username }
    }
}

ddb.getItem (params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // Oh well
    } else {
        context.succeed (data.Item)
    }
})
```

You will probably want Query though, that way you can return multiple items

#### Query

- **Requires** : TableName, (KeyConditionExpression && ExpressionAttributeValues) || KeyConditions
- **Optional** : ReturnConsumedCapacity, QueryFilter, ProjectionExpression, Limit, etc.

This would be:

```
var table = 'usatUsers'
var params = {
    TableName : table,
    KeyConditions: {
        "userType": {
            "AttributeValueList": [{
                S: event.type
            }],
            "ComparisonOperator" : "EQ"
        }
    }
}

ddb.query (params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // Oh well
    } else {
        context.succeed (data)
    }
})
```

Also, be careful of reserved keys [CHECK THIS LIST](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html) to make sure all your names are compliant